# Resolving apparent circular dependency: class A having a method that takes in class B, while class B having a member of type class A

Tags: c++, oop, methods, member, circular-dependency

I have two classes that I want to define, `Position` and `TangentVector`, partially given as follows:

```
class Position
{
public:
    Position(double x, double y, double z);
    
    // getters
    double x(){ return m_x };
    double y(){ return m_x };
    double z(){ return m_x };

    void translate(const TangentVector& tangent_vector);
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
}
```

```
class TangentVector
{
public:
    Tangent(double x, double y, double z, Position position);

    // getters
    double x(){ return m_x };
    double y(){ return m_x };
    double z(){ return m_x };
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
    Position m_position;
}
```

The key thing to note with the classes is that `TangentVector` has a member of type `Position` (`TangentVector` depends on `Position`) while `Position` has a method that takes in an argument of type `const TangentVector&` (`Position` depends on `TangentVector`?).

For context's sake, `Position` is intended to represent a point on the unit sphere, and `TangentVector` describes a vector tangent to the sphere, with the origin of the vector specified by a `Position`. Since the definition of a `VectorTangent` requires a `Position` to be specified, it seems reasonable to say that `VectorTangent` depends on `Position`. However, now I want to define a function that takes a `Position` on the sphere, and "translates" it along the sphere by a direction and distance given by `TangentVector`. I would really like this `translate` method to live in the `Position` class, since it a function that modifies the state of `Position`. This would lend itself to the following usage, which I feel is fairly natural:

```
Position position{ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
TangentVector tangent_vector{ 0.0, PI/2, 0.0, position };
position.translate(tangent_vector);                        // Now { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
```

However, I fear that this results in some circular dependency. So...

- Is this case an example of circular dependency? Is this case bad practice?
- If so, how can this circular dependency be avoided? How can this code be modified such that it is in-line with good OOP practices?

(I considered making the `Position m_position` member a raw pointer instead. In this case, however, I intend `m_position` to be fully owned by `TangentVector`, rather than allow the possibility of it being altered external to the class. In the example usage code, I do not want the `translate` method to modify `tangent_vector`, which would happen if `tangent_vector`'s constructor took in `position` as a pointer and stored it as a member.)

Comment: As this question got closed in the meantime, to comment on your questions and not about forward declarations (that are the technical solution):
Q1> Is this case an example of circular dependency? Is this case bad practice? 
A1> It's a circular dependency that comes from a model, so you just model the world as it is. One entity needs the other to operate.

Comment: Q2> If so, how can this circular dependency be avoided? How can this code be modified such that it is in-line with good OOP practices?
A2> The code currently appears OK. Theoretically you could extract a helper static method that does the translation, but then your `Position` object would be very anemic (it only stores data). The best idea might be to follow SOLID, and try to keep functionality in a single class. Right now, it feels like `translate` has its place in a `Position`.

Comment: SOLID and actually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: In the end it is unexact science, in this simple example there is nothing wrong, but in future you might want to avoid situations when a single class needs N other classes to perform its function.

Comment: And just to be more wordy ;), some possible solutions are:
* use TV as Position factory (but then instead it needs to know how to create positions and possibly access Position internal data);
* instead of passing TV pass only what's needed to perform the computation (== 3 doubles + position) this way you avoid spelling out TV (you can see it's an ugly idea here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Position` takes only a reference to `class TangentVector`. Therefore you might pre-declare `TangentVector` as `class TangentVector;` before the declaration of `class Position`:

```
class TangentVector;

class Position
{
public:
    Position(double x, double y, double z);
    
    // getters
    double x(){ return m_x };
    double y(){ return m_x };
    double z(){ return m_x };

    void translate(const TangentVector& tangent_vector);
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
};
```